# What are the files list-l and list-c in Ubuntu after fsck on boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fsck

I did fsck on ext4 on reboot on Ubuntu 9.10 by:

`cd /forcefsck && reboot`.

This went fine, but two new files appeared afterwards in /:

`list-l` and `list-c`. Both are empty.

What is the purpose of these files?

Thank you

Comment: Does `grep list-l /etc/init/* /etc/init.d/*` return anything? I can't find anything definitive about this online, but you're not the only person to have reported this kind of behavior.

Comment: No, `grep list /etc/init/* /etc/init.d/*` returns irrelevant lines (part of comments in the scripts). I suspect both files are related to the forced fsck at start-up. After the fsck the system rebooted and these files were already there. On the next reboot they updated their time stamps, which means something is recreating them. Their permissions are 0600, owned by root:root. Why they are there? What is their purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this OpenSUSE forum post](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/applications/405801-empty-files-directory.html#post1973897) describing this behavior as a bug in the ATI graphics driver, fglrx. Unfortunately, its link to the ATI bug tracker is broken, but the post gives some details. You may want to try upgrading fglrx or modifying `/etc/ati/authatieventsd.sh`.